# Start animating when a div reaches a certain distance from the top of the page

Tags: jquery, menu, scroll

I have a menu that floats within the window when scrolling.
Currently my menu always stays 190px from the top of the window.
I'm using the dimensions plugin and here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
menuYloc = parseInt($('#mainMenu').css('top').substring(0,$('#mainMenu').css('top').indexOf('px')))
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var offset = menuYloc+$(document).scrollTop()+'px';
        $('#mainMenu').animate({top:offset},{duration:600,queue:false});  
    });
});
```

What I would like to accomplish is that when you are scrolled to the top of the page the menu is 190px away from the top. However when you start scrolling down the menu scrolls with the page until it reaches 50px away from the top of the window, then it starts to float, always staying 50px from the top of the window, unless you scroll back up to the top of the page.

Hope that makes sense and please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions, the only thing is that I would like to preserve the animation. I've created a jsfiddle that compares my original function with the two suggestions. Check it out and let me know if its possible: http://jsfiddle.net/b793h/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks @twsansbury and @andy. Looks like I've figured this out with your nudges in the right direction.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
var minDistance = 50;
var startDistance = 190;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var newDistance = (scrollTop + minDistance);
    if (scrollTop > startDistance - minDistance) {
        $('#mainMenu').animate({top:newDistance},{duration:600,queue:false});
    } else {
        $('#mainMenu').animate({top:startDistance},{duration:600,queue:false});
    }
});
```

And here is a jsfiddle that shows the comparison between the three solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/cpL69/

Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var minDistance = 50;
var startDistance = 190;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > startDistance - minDistance) {
        $('#mainMenu').css('top', scrollTop + minDistance);
    } else {
        $('#mainMenu').css('top', startDistance);
    }
});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/d52wr/

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to change both the `position` and `top` attribute based on the scroll distance.  This approach allows the browser to handle the display during its render loop while the scroll is occurring, resulting in smoother transitions when compared to a `top` only approach, as flickering artifacts can occur due to event processing.

```
var minDistance = 50;
var startDistance = 190;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop > startDistance - minDistance) {
    $('#mainMenu2').css({position: 'fixed',
                         top: minDistance});
  } else {
      $('#mainMenu2').css({position: 'absolute',
                           top: startDistance});
  }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing a side-by-side comparison between the two approaches: http://jsfiddle.net/nKAtB/.  In some browsers, when scrolling quickly or large distances, a flickering effect can be observed with the div being positioned after every scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#animatedElement').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideUp");
        }
    });
});
```

Replace #animatedElement with the ID or class of the element you want animated.
Replace slideUp with an animation class.
400 represents the space between the element and the top of the screen. The animation activates when the element is 400px from the top of the screen. Increase this number to make the animaton activate sooner.